# From which equation of motion was this formula derived from in physics

Tags: derivatives, physics

When solving problems involving projectile motion I use:

$\sqrt{2 * \dfrac{\text{height above ground}}{9.8}}$

Eg calculate the time it takes for a bomb to impact if it is travelling 4.9km above ground I simply do:

$\sqrt{2 * \dfrac{49000}{9.8}}$ and get the correct answer of 100 seconds.

However, from traditional equations of projectile motion ( Which I am required to use, and not this formula) I have to use either one of these which relate to the vertical velocity of the object:

[image]

So my question is the above formula mentioned derived from the above 3 ?

Comment: This is under the assumption that the vertical component of velocity is initially zero. That's a key condition. With that in mind, which of your kinematic equations involves time, height, and acceleration?

Answer (score 0):

The 2nd one. Solve for y=height and $u_0=0$.

$V^2 = 2 a h$ , $a=g=9.8$

h=$\sqrt{(v^2/2g)}$

The. Plug this into eother eq1 or 3.

Answer (score 0):

If you use the equation

$$\Delta y = u_yt + \frac{1}{2}a_yt^2$$

with $u_y = 0$ and $a_y = g$, you obtain

\begin{align*}
\Delta y & = \frac{1}{2}gt^2\\
2\Delta y & = gt^2\\
\frac{2 \Delta y}{g} & = t^2\\
\sqrt{\frac{2 \Delta y}{g}} & = t
\end{align*}

Substituting $-4900~\text{m}$ for $\Delta y$ and $-9.8~\dfrac{\text{m}}{\text{s}^2}$ for $g$ yields

$$t = \sqrt{\frac{2\Delta y}{g}} = \sqrt{\frac{2 \cdot -4900~\text{m}}{-9.8~\frac{\text{m}}{\text{s}^2}}} = \sqrt{1000~\text{s}^2}$$

where I have used the fact that $$4.9~\text{km} \cdot \frac{1000~\text{m}}{\text{km}} = 4900~\text{m}$$